# How to find the mean of a given variable in NetCDF regardless of latitude and longitude?

Tags: ubuntu, netcdf, climate, climate-data-operators

I have extracted temperature `t2m` data from a NetCDF file for certain regions, and now I would like to find the overall mean temperature per timestamp for the given regions. The dimension of the NetCDF files is the following:

```
Dimensions:    (latitude: 197, longitude: 513, time: 108)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -180.0 -179.8 -179.5 ... -52.5 -52.25 -52.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... 41.5 41.25 41.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1970-01-01T01:00:00 ... 1970-01-05T12:00:00
Data variables:
    crs        int32 ...
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
```

I would like to find the overall mean temperature `t2m` for the region for each timestamp? Can it be done by `cdo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `cdo fldmean *.nc meantemperature.nc` in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `cdo timmean input_files*.nc output_file.nc`. It works perfectly.